# How to access an Angular2 component's methods from another component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, multi-select

I am working on an **NgForm** that is supposed to have a "Reset all fields"-button. I can access NgForm.reset() to reset most of the fields. But I have a couple of instances of a custom multiselect component that is excluded from the reset-method.

The custom multiselect is basically just an `<angular2-multiselect>` with some `<items>` attached to it, and it has an "X" button that will clear it's value(s) which works fine. This happens through `(onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)` on the `<angular2-multiselect>`.

I am trying to fire this method from another button inside the same NgForm. But I can't seem to understand how to do so. I've tried to make my own method too

```
<multiselect name="myMultiselect"/>
   // Lots of options

<button (click)="myMultiselect.onDeSelectAll($event)"/>
   // or
<button (click)="ResetMultiSelect($event)"/>
```

I've also tried to make my own code that does the same thing. This is how I try to do it in typescript:

```
public myMultiselect : MultiSelect;

function ResetMultiSelect(items: any)
{
   myMultiselect.selectedItems = items;
   // or
   this.myForm.myMultiselect.selectedItems = items;
}
```

I've tried to set `myMultiselect.selectedItems` to **null**, **undefined**, and **[]** (empty array). Out of the three only [] seems to work. But when I look in the inspector it tells me that `this.selectedItems.split is not a function`. So although I get the result I want this way, I get it wrong way.

So my question is basically either

**A**: Is there a way for me to set `selectedItems` of my `multiselect` to be something that clears all options from a function that is triggered by the `button`?

or **B**:
Is there a good way for my button to find and call my `multiselectComponent`'s `onDeSelectAll()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [angular template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) to get a reference of your angular component. Then you could easily call the public method you like on your child component like:

```
<multiselect #myMultiselect></multiselect>
<button (onClick)="myMultiselect.onDeSelectAll($event)">Click Here</button>
```

You could also use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) decorator in your component .ts to retrieve the component you want by its given template variable.

Comment: This was perfect. The `$event` I got from doing it this way did not work with `onDeSelectAll()` so I just made a new method in my typescript that set the selection to an empty array instead with `myMultiselect.selectedItems = []` and then updated the view. I then called this method from my button just like in your example.